# New-ADUser -POBox returns "A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values"

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have a script that creates users but sometimes failes with

```
New-ADUser -name "test" -pobox "Streetname Streetname2 99, EU-1010 Country"
A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values
```

So I did a eleminitaion of parameters where I commented out one after another, the failing link was POBox.
Many other posts sugests that -Country is a common fault but this is not the case here (we are using country codes and everything works fine).

I can't seem to find when it works and not, is there any limits to POBox-name? Anything that can cause the failure?
Microsoft Docs just says "String value"

Comment: So, it works when you remove the `-POBox` parameter and just do `New-ADUser -Name test`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes but in reality we are using like 20 parameters but I have tested all (removing one at the time) and the script completes only when I remove -pobox

Comment: I just saw the update, makes a lot more sense now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the [`postBoxOffice` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-postofficebox) (to which the `-POBox` parameter maps), is restricted to a maximum of 40 characters.

The sample string in your question, "Streetname Streetname2 99, EU-1010 Country", is 42 characters long :)

You can inspect the maximum length of any string-syntax attribute by inspecting the `rangeUpper` attribute on the corresponding schema entry for the target attribute:

```
PS ~> $poBoxSchema = Get-ADObject -Filter 'lDAPDisplayName -eq "postOfficeBox"' -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemaNamingContext -Properties rangeUpper
PS ~> $poBoxSchema.rangeUpper
40
```

Comment: That was easy! Where did you find the information? For future reference

Comment: Wow, not sure how this __is not__ specified in the parameter section of the `New-ADUser` MS Docs -_- awesome finding tho

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That wouldn't be the right place to document it. If someone modifies their schema to have different constraints, the documentation (or worse, the tooling) would then be in conflict with reality :)

Comment: @Salve I've updated the answer with how to find it in the AD Schema